# Can I use refactored storyboard in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, storyboard, uistoryboard

I read about the refactoring storyboards in iOS.

Refactoring storyboard means that we can submodule the view controller in the storyboard and connect with the references.

So I want to know that, is this feature compatible with iOS 8? I haven't tried yet this technique and multiple storyboards in a project.

Please let me know should I use this in iOS 8 targeted project or not?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with refactoring storyboards? Refactoring normal means rename/extracting/rewrite code so I don't see why this would not be compatible with iOS 8.

Comment: This is a good question, no reason to close it. It's about a new feature introduced in 2015.

Comment: @bpapa, but what kind of answer is expected to this kind of question? To me it sounds too generic. Or the answer would contain only "yes, it's compatible", "no, it's not compatible".

Comment: Isn't this a Q & A site?

Comment: Answer being well mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30772291/2710486)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because insufficient research. The answer is in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the ["Refactoring One Storyboard into Multiple Storyboards" article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/RefactorStoryboard.html), it says

> Compatibility: Storyboard references require an app targeting at least iOS 8.0, OS X 10.10, or watchOS 1.0.

Comment: Thanks, bpapa.
Now I can use this feature in my app.