# XCode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b) - Extremely slow, is it the StackViews which are issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, uistackview

I am using the Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b), with a MacBook Pro 2017 8 GBs of RAM. The Xcode has been very very slow in the storyboard,is it because of I am using lot of stack views. Does using a lot of stack views create problem and how many stack views can be used at once? To give an idea below is the structure I am using -

[image]

Comment: I already have same issue when use many stackview, I think Xcode need more computing with stackview, you should use uiview with constraint instead of stackview in some unnecessary case

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any specification or standard which says something like this.

Comment: sorry. this is my opinion. You can read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710757/too-many-views-in-storyboard-xcode-running-slow

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw that earlier but that is not specific to stack views. I have only couple of views which are full of stack views as posted in the screen shot above.

Comment: You should try many ways in that, not only accepted answer

Comment: How many VCs do you have in a storyboard file?

Comment: At present there are only 3, however it would be more then 5 view controllers in a tab view controller.