# How to connect a Navigation Controller in one storyboard to View Controllers in another storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

[image]

Here is my Navigation controller that has one View Controller in the stack, but I have another storyboard with Viewcontrollers I want to add to the stack. I have the Views separated in order to better organize my Views and to have less views per Storyboard. How do I add Views from the referenced storyboard to the Navigation controller shown?

[image]

Right now I have the reference pointing to another Navigation controller in the second storyboard, but I wouldn't have a back arrow to the viewcontroller in the first Navigation Controller.

Comment: read https://medium.com/@wilson.balderrama/how-to-segue-between-storyboards-86c582f976f7

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Perfect.

Comment: @pgdev : thanks adding it with bit more detail as answer below :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I know how to segue between two different storyboards. That’s why I have the storyboard reference. However, I’m trying to connect a view controller from the second storyboard to stack  it in the Nav Controller in the first storyboard.

Comment: @EricAgredo did you managed to solve this?

Comment: This worked for me on iOS 12: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973831/7180858

Answer (score 0):

In the Storyboard A where you have a navigation controller add a Segue to Storyboard B (Settings) and make sure that you also write the View controller ID (MyViewControler) that you like from within Storyboard B in the **Referenced ID**

[image]

in Storyboard B (Settings) add a navigation controller and set the root view controller to the one that you like (MyViewControler) this navigation will be use only show the UI as it will be in the navigation controller from Storyboard A and will not be part of the navigation stack, This is because you add **Referenced ID** !!!