# How can I connect a UITabBarController to ViewControllers in separate Storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm writing a small news bulletin and notification app with a group of other programmers. We're trying to be proactive about task separation and safe merging to our git repo by separating logical sections in our app (News Feed, Contacts, etc.) into entirely separate Storyboards.

This is working really well in terms of merging and task separation, but we're running into issues connecting these views to a UITabBarController (Note that the UITabBarController is also in a separate Storyboard).

I have looked at many other SO threads and tried tutorials online for connecting Views to a UITabBarController programmatically without success. Here are a few I have looked at:

[UITabBarController with diffent storyboard file for each ViewController of the TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924064/uitabbarcontroller-with-diffent-storyboard-file-for-each-viewcontroller-of-the-t)

[Using multiple storyboards with a TabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943892/using-multiple-storyboards-with-a-tabbarcontroller)

[UITabBarController and Multiple Storyboards](http://dreitalks.com/2014/04/05/uitabbarcontroller-and-multiple-storyboards/)

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks!